# Using dplyr to mutate the following rows after meeting condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to add a new column, with character strings based on another column, via an ifelse statement in dplyr. When the condition is met, I also want the following two rows to also show the same value.

I show an example from the mtcars dataset

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(type=ifelse(mpg>20,"Event", "No event")) %>%
  mutate(type=ifelse(type=="Event", lead(type),`type`))
```

What I am trying to do here is produce a new column called type, which if the `mpg>20`, I want the row to state "event" and if not "no event". However, I also want the two rows following the `mpg>20` also to show "Event", even if they don't meet the criteria.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Do you want next two rows after `mpg > 20` to be "Event" or previous rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the problem correctly.
However you can try to modify the logical expression inside `if_else`:

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(type = if_else(mpg > 20 | lag(mpg) > 20 | lag(mpg, n = 2) > 20, "Event", "No event"))

    mpg     type
1  21.0    Event
2  21.0    Event
3  22.8    Event
4  21.4    Event
5  18.7    Event
6  18.1    Event
7  14.3 No event
8  24.4    Event
9  22.8    Event
10 19.2    Event
11 17.8    Event
12 16.4 No event
13 17.3 No event
14 15.2 No event
15 10.4 No event
16 10.4 No event
17 14.7 No event
18 32.4    Event
```

Comment: Not quite what I was after. If MPG >20, I want that row to be "Event", and the following two rows to be "Event". It does not matter if the following two rows exceed MPG>20, For all other rows I want "No event"

Comment: Hm. If use my code on `mtcars` rows 4,5 and 6 get `"Event"`. In row four `mpg > 20` is TRUE. In rows 5 and 6 we have `mpg < 20`. 
Maybe you post your desired output

Comment: Sorry, misread and misunderstood your response previously. Totally correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For a general solution, you can use `zoo`s rolling function. You can adjust the window size based on how much you want to look back.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

mtcars %>% mutate(type = rollapplyr(mpg > 20, 3, any, partial = TRUE))


#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  type
#1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  TRUE
#2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  TRUE
#3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  TRUE
#4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1  TRUE
#5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2  TRUE
#6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1  TRUE
#7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4 FALSE
#8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2  TRUE
#9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2  TRUE
#10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4  TRUE
#11 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4  TRUE
#12 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3 FALSE
#13 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3 FALSE
#...
#...
```

You can then change it to `"Event"`, `"No Event"` using `ifelse` :

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(type = ifelse(rollapplyr(mpg > 20, 3, any, partial = TRUE), 
                      'Event', 'No event'))
```

Or without `ifelse` :

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(type = c('No event', 'Event')
                  [rollapplyr(mpg > 20, 3, any, partial = TRUE) + 1])
```